# Picking up Greyhound bus tickets from a different station than origin

Tags: usa, transportation, buses, greyhound

Suppose I wanted to buy my Greyhound tickets on-line.  The closest station from my house is not the one I will be departing from though.  The question is, can I pick up Greyhound tickets from a station that is different from the one where I will be departing from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Greyhound in Canada you can do this no problem.  You can go to any Greyhound station and purchase a trip from any place of departure to any destination.

Comment: Would just add: Greyhound Canada tickets are only able to be picked up at any Canadian station and US tickets only in American stations.

Answer (score 1):

You can pick up a Greyhound bus ticket that you purchased online from any Greyhound bus station. I've done this on several occasions and there's never been an issue. All of Greyhound is tied into the same system so they don't really care what your departing station is when it comes to printing out a will call ticket.